# Ajax Issue Not Displaying the warning already rated is not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im very tire working this code on wordpress. technically im planning to build a rating system for movies.

so my plan is, when the user is not login then popup the warning saying "Please login first before rating." same with when you already rated the movies then popup this "You have already rated this movie".

the function rating is working fine. however the warning popup is not showing why? please help me. i dont have any error on my console.

Here my code.

rating-script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Function to handle rating submission
    function handleRatingSubmission(postID, ratingValue) {
      // Check if user is logged in
      if (ratingAjax.isLoggedIn === false) {
        // User is not logged in, show error message
        $('.rating-error-message').text('Please login first before rating.').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        return;
      }
  
      // Send AJAX request to check if user has already rated
      $.ajax({
        url: ratingAjax.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          action: 'check_already_rated',
          post_id: postID
        },
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.alreadyRated) {
            // User has already rated, show error message
            $('.rating-error-message').text('You have already rated this movie.').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
          } else {
            // User has not rated, proceed with rating submission
            // Send AJAX request to update rating
            $.ajax({
              url: ratingAjax.ajaxurl,
              type: 'POST',
              data: {
                action: 'update_rating',
                post_id: postID,
                rating_value: ratingValue * 2 // Multiply the rating by 2 to convert it back to the original scale of 1-10
              },
              success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                  // Rating updated successfully
                  // Display success message
                  $('.rating-success-message').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
  
                  // Update the rating display
                  updateRatingDisplay(postID, ratingValue);
  
                  // Update the average rating display
                  var averageRating = parseFloat(response.average_rating).toFixed(2);
                  $('.rating-info[data-post-id="' + postID + '"] .average-rating').text('Average Rating: ' + averageRating);
  
                  // Update the total ratings display
                  var totalRatings = response.total_ratings;
                  $('.rating-info[data-post-id="' + postID + '"] .total-ratings').text('Total Ratings: ' + totalRatings);
                } else {
                  // Error occurred during rating update
                  // You can add additional error handling logic here
                }
              },
              error: function() {
                // Error occurred during AJAX request
                // You can add additional error handling logic here
              }
            });
          }
        },
        error: function() {
          // Error occurred during AJAX request
          // You can add additional error handling logic here
        }
      });
    }
  
    // Function to update the rating display
    function updateRatingDisplay(postID, ratingValue) {
      // Add your code here to update the rating display
      // This function should update the visual representation of the rating based on the given rating value and post ID
      // You can modify the DOM elements to reflect the updated rating
    }
  
    // Handle hover effect on rating stars
    $('.rating-stars .star').hover(function() {
      var value = $(this).data('value');
      $(this).prevAll().addBack().addClass('hover');
      $(this).nextAll().removeClass('hover');
      $(this).parent().next('.rating-hover-text').text(value);
    }, function() {
      $(this).prevAll().addBack().removeClass('hover');
      $(this).parent().next('.rating-hover-text').text('');
    });
  
    // Handle rating submission
    $('.rating-stars .star').click(function() {
      var postID = $(this).data('post-id');
      var ratingValue = $(this).data('value');
  
      // Handle rating submission for logged-in users only
      handleRatingSubmission(postID, ratingValue);
    });
  });
```

functions.php

```
<?php
// Enqueue necessary scripts and styles
function enqueue_rating_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('rating-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/rating-script.js', array('jquery'), false);

    // Localize the script to pass the ajaxurl value
    wp_localize_script('rating-script', 'ratingAjax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'isLoggedIn' => is_user_logged_in() // Add this line to pass the user login status
    ));

    wp_enqueue_style('rating-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/rating-style.css');
    wp_register_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('main');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Lora&family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap', array(), null );
    wp_register_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('script');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.1/css/all.css', array(), null );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_rating_scripts');


// AJAX handler to check if user has already rated
function check_already_rated() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_send_json_error(array('alreadyRated' => false)); // User is not logged in, return false
    }

    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $ratings = get_field('ratings', $post_id);

    foreach ($ratings as $rating) {
        if ($rating['user_id'] == $user_id) {
            wp_send_json_error(array('alreadyRated' => true)); // User has already rated, return true
        }
    }

    wp_send_json_success(array('alreadyRated' => false)); // User has not rated, return false
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_already_rated', 'check_already_rated');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_already_rated', 'check_already_rated');

// AJAX handler for updating ratings
function update_rating() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Please login first before rating.')); // Send error response if user is not logged in
    }

    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $rating_value = $_POST['rating_value'];

    // Check if user has already rated
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $ratings = get_field('ratings', $post_id);
    foreach ($ratings as $rating) {
        if ($rating['user_id'] == $user_id) {
            wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'You have already rated this movie.')); // Send error response if user has already rated
        }
    }

    // Update ACF repeater field for the post
    $new_rating = array(
        'rating_value' => min($rating_value, 5), // Set the rating value to a maximum of 5
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'timestamp' => current_time('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
    $ratings[] = $new_rating;
    update_field('ratings', $ratings, $post_id);

    // Recalculate average rating and update ACF field
    $rating_values = wp_list_pluck($ratings, 'rating_value');
    $average_rating = count($rating_values) > 0 ? round(array_sum($rating_values) / count($rating_values), 2) : null; // Round the average rating to 2 decimal places
    update_field('average_rating', $average_rating, $post_id);

    // Return success response with updated average rating and total ratings
    $response = array(
        'success' => true,
        'average_rating' => $average_rating,
        'total_ratings' => count($ratings)
    );
    wp_send_json($response);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_update_rating', 'update_rating');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_rating', 'update_rating');

function display_rating_stars() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $rating_value = get_field('rating', $post_id);
    $ratings = get_field('ratings', $post_id);
    $average_rating = get_field('average_rating', $post_id);

    // Calculate the maximum number of stars (5)
    $max_stars = 5;

    // Calculate the number of full stars
    $full_stars = 0;
    if (is_array($ratings)) { // Check if $ratings is an array before counting
        $full_stars = min(floor($rating_value), $max_stars); // Limit the full stars to a maximum of 5
    }

    // Output the rating stars HTML
    echo '<div class="rating-stars">';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $max_stars; $i++) {
        $star_class = ($i <= $full_stars) ? 'star active' : 'star';
        echo '<span class="' . $star_class . '" data-value="' . $i . '" data-post-id="' . $post_id . '">&#9733;</span>';
    }
    echo '</div>';

    // Output the average rating and total ratings
    echo '<div class="rating-info">';
    if (!is_null($average_rating)) {
        echo 'Average Rating: ' . number_format($average_rating, 2);
    }
    if (!is_null($ratings) && is_array($ratings)) { // Check if $ratings is an array before counting
        echo 'Total Ratings: ' . count($ratings);
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

acf-input.js

```
(function($) {
    acf.add_action('ready', function() {
        // Enable the ACF Number field for the rating ACF field
        $('.acf-field-number input[type="number"]').on('input', function() {
            var $input = $(this);
            var $field = $input.closest('.acf-field');
            var $label = $field.find('.acf-label');

            if ($input.val()) {
                $label.addClass('active');
            } else {
                $label.removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

single.php

```
                    <div class="rating-success-message" style="display: none;">
                        Rating submitted successfully!
                    </div>
                    <div class="rating-error-message" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: check your console log for any related errors

Comment: there is no error bro

Comment: add the following command : "debugger;" at the top of your "function handleRatingSubmission { debugger; ...." and follow your code step by step in the browser console

Answer (score 1):

`updateRatingDisplay` (and other things) may not be reachable where you are calling them. AJAX is asynchronous, so you can add `async` in front of your function then `await` right in front of the two ajax key words to create two separate ajax statements. I am not exactly sure what the issue is and there are many ways to go about this but I rewrote your function without running it. Instead of async you could also set `async: false` in your ajax call. Please let me know if works.

```
async function handleRatingSubmission(postID, ratingValue)  {
  if (ratingAjax.isLoggedIn === false) {
    $('.rating-error-message').text('Please login first before rating.').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    return;
  }
        
  let proceed_;
  let second_ajax_success;
        
  proceed_ = await $.ajax({
    url: ratingAjax.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      action: 'check_already_rated',
      post_id: postID
    },
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.alreadyRated) {
        return { 
          value: false, 
          error: false
        }
      } else {
        return { 
          value: true, 
          error: false
        }
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      return { 
        error: true, 
        value: false
      }
    }
  });
        
   if (proceed_.value === true && proceed_.error === false) { 
     second_ajax_success = await $.ajax({
       url: ratingAjax.ajaxurl,
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
         action: 'update_rating',
         post_id: postID,
         rating_value: ratingValue * 2
       },
       success: function(response) {
         if (response.success) {
           return { 
             error: false, 
             value: true
           };
         } else {
           return { 
             value: false, 
             error: false
           };
         }
       },
       error: function() {
         return { 
           error: true, 
           value: false
         }
       }
     });
   } else if(proceed_.value === false && proceed_.error === false) {
     $('.rating-error-message').text('You have already rated this movie.').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
   } else { 
     // error - request not sent through
   }
        
    if (typeof second_ajax_success === 'object') {
      if (second_ajax_success.value === true && second_ajax_success.error === false) { 
        $('.rating-success-message').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        updateRatingDisplay(postID, ratingValue);
        var averageRating = parseFloat(response.average_rating).toFixed(2);
        $('.rating-info[data-post-id="' + postID + '"] .average-rating').text('Average Rating: ' + averageRating);
        var totalRatings = response.total_ratings;
        $('.rating-info[data-post-id="' + postID + '"] .total-ratings').text('Total Ratings: ' + totalRatings);
      } else if(second_ajax_success.value === false && second_ajax_success.error === false) {
        // error - request went through but undesired response
      } else { 
        // error - request not sent through
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the code with errors in mind